# How to configure B2B TUA Spartacus with Automatic Multi-Site Configuration?

Tags: angular, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

everyone.

As explained in this section ([Automatic Multi-Site Configuration](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/automatic-context-configuration/)), it is suggested to simple leave the *context.baseSite* property in *SiteContextConfig* which works well with TUA Spartacus storefront with B2C but redirects to **b2btelcospa** automatically when enabled B2B. The storefront is built as explained in this section ([Building the TUA Spartacus Storefront Using 4.1 Libraries](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/building-the-tua-storefront-from-libraries-4.1/)).

The SPA-TUA node module has these values hard-coded in it. How can we override this and configure B2B TUA Spartacus with Automatic Multi-Site Configuration?

[image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuTFZ.png)